# Training a keras model using TPU pods?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tpu

I was wondering if anyone has an example of using a keras model on a TPU pod?

I have a model creating method which returns a keras model which is compiled within a TPU strategy scope, as recommended by many examples on using TPUs with keras. This works with v3-8 but gives an error when tried with more cores (specifically v3-32):

```
with strategy.scope():
    keras_model = create_model()
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=3e-5, epsilon=1e-08)
    keras_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

When running model.fit, it fails with the following error:

```
Failed copying input tensor from /job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:worker/replica:0/task:1/device:CPU:0 in order to run DatasetFromGraph: FetchOutputs node : not found [Op:DatasetFromGraph]
```

The model input are in the form of numpy arrays. Is perhaps a tensorflow.data.Dataset required?

Comment: I've now tried with Tf.data.Dataset without success, gives the same error

Comment: If the issue is not with the dataset, you can check that your TPU pod and VM have the same Tensorflow versions. You can see `... node : not found [Op:...]` type of errors when TPU and VM have mismatching Tensorflow versions.

Comment: I have tf 2.3.1 and the same version on the TPU/TPU pod but makes no difference unfortunately. What is weird is that it works fine with v3-8. Should also work with v3-32 right out of the box with the same code, right?

Comment: yes, it should have. Could you get a small code to reproduce the issue? or try out some other TPU model on your TPU pod, for example this one (make sure you adjust the batch size to be a multiple on the number of TPU cores, 32 in your case): https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/guide/tpu.ipynb

Comment: Yes, I'll try this code sample with V3-32 and see if it produces the same error.

Comment: I have the same issue, does anyone have the answer? my code works perfectly with v3-8, but not v3-32. I am thinking to speed up by using of v3-32. Thanks.